# Payments with confirmation

Tags: security, credentials, paypal, masspay

Any method of payments through the API requires credentials, but for security reasons I don't want to store credentials on my server.
Can I do payments like this:
1. Using the API make Mass Payments
2. After that, login to my PayPal account and confirm payments
3. Using the API get information about payments

Answer (score 0):

From PayPal forum:

> Unfortunately to use any of the API's
>   you would pass over the API
>   credentials in the API call.